# Laravel inserting multiple records in table

Tags: php, laravel

I try to do that

```
    $names = $request->input('name');
    $forid= $request->input('forid');
    $ArrayNames = explode(",",$names);

    $dataArrayNames = array();
    foreach($ArrayNames as $name)
    {
        $dataArrayNames[] = array('name'=>$name, 'forId' => $forid);
    }

    Model::insert(array($dataArrayNames));
```

But i get the error message 
" preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array "

NOTE : $request->input('name') = 'nameA,nameB,nameC'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making an array of an array.
Try this.

```
Model::insert($dataArrayNames);
```